# Unable to create trigger with syntax which matches documentation

Tags: postgresql

Trying to create this trigger fails with `ERROR: syntax error at or near "function"`

```
create trigger set_foo_bar_value 
    before update on foo_table 
    for each row execute function set_foo_bar();
```

Yet this matches the [examples here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtrigger.html)

Answer (score 2):

The docs are for postgres >= 11, I was using postgres 10.

I needed to replace `function` with `procedure`

Comment: This caveat really does need mentioning in the documentation.